# why my uploaded tables_rates don't work

Tags: magento

Working on Magento web site with two languages, whene i upload my shipping rules under   .

```
Config => syetem => Shipping`   


Pays,Région/État,"Code postal","Poids (et au-delà)","Tarif de livraison" 
BEL,*,,5000.0000,17.0000
BEL,*,,4000.0000,15.0000
BLM,*,,4000.0000,29.0000...
```

The rules are not working at all !?

Can you help please

Comment: go through this thoroughly http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a config error, the client changed the free shipment to yes,  thats why :s 
Thanks